# Understanding the function $s^\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Consider the function $f(s) = s^{\lambda}$ where $s$ is a real variable and  $\lambda$ is a complex constant with $\Re \lambda > 0$.

I want to understand $f$ when $s \in I=[0,1]$.

1. Is $f$ defined at $s = 0$?
2. Is $f$ differentiable on $I$? If so, is its derivative just $\lambda s^{\lambda -1}?$

My difficulty lies in the fact that $s^\lambda$ is, by definition, equal to $\exp {(\lambda \log s)}$. Of course, since $s$ is real, $\log s$ here is simply the natural logarithm of $s$. If I follow this reasoning, $f$ is not defined at $s=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Powers of $0$ are a sure way to get into arguments.  In the complex case that's doubly true...  Yes, the general definition of complex powers excludes $s=0$.  Of course if $\Re \lambda > 0$, you do have $\lim_{s \to 0} f(s) = 0$
(for all branches of $f$).

2) Again, $s=0$ is problematic.  For $0 < \Re \lambda < 1$, 
even if you define $f(0) = 0$, $\lim_{s \to 0+} \frac{f(s) - 0}{s - 0} = \infty$.